API is working at development, but in production fails
I am trying to run my site in nextjs (typescript) with my API. When I run it in development, the API works, but when I run on production (vercel), it throws a timeout.
In the API call, I pass one parameter with three possible values. Only one value is working in production. It is important me to get all the data at once and not with pagination because I use this data for charts. The data I fetch from google firebase.
Here is my API:
import { googleDb } from "@/lib/firebase";
import { Query, DocumentData } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

type Data = {
    documentId: string;
    [key: string]: any;
};

export async function GET(
    req: NextRequest,
) {
    if (!googleDb) {
        console.error("Problem with googleDb")
        return new NextResponse("Firebase Firestore is not initialized", { status: 500 });
    }

    const paramName = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("paramName");

    try {
        const collectionRef = googleDb.collection("collectionName")
        let query: Query<DocumentData> = collectionRef;

        if (kingdom !== "n") {
            query = query.where("creteria", "==", paramName as string);
        }

        const querySnapshot = await query.get()

        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            console.error("No matching documents found.");
            return new NextResponse("No matching documents found", { status: 500 });
        }

        const data: Data[] = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            data.push({ documentId: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
        });

        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ data }), {
            status: 200,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching data from Firestore: ${error}`);
        return new NextResponse("Initial Server Error", { status: 500 });
    }
}

One of my API calls:
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchFirestoreData = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await fetchData("/api/google/getFirestoreData?kingdom=n");
                setFirestoreData(data);
                filterData(data.data);
            } catch (error) {
                setError({ message: error } as { message: string });
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };

        fetchFirestoreData();
    }, []);

fetchData function:
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const fetchData = async ( url: string, options = {} ) => { 
    try {
        const fetchWithTimeout = (timeoutMs: number) => {
            return Promise.race([
                fetch(url, { cache: 'force-cache' }),
                new Promise<never>((_, reject) => 
                    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("API timed out")), timeoutMs)
                )
            ]);
        };

        const response = await fetchWithTimeout(30000);
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        toast.error(`Error retrieving data: ${error}`);
        throw new Error('Could not get data')
    }
}

export { fetchData };

My API is working fine in development, but in production, it fails.

You're using Application Default Credentials (ADC) to authenticate. Presumably, locally, you've either gcloud application-default login at some point in the past or you're export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key.json. If so, when you run on Vercel, you'll also need to authenticate and probably by using an environment variable (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) and a Service Account key (unless Workload Identity Federation is supported).

Aha! Vercel (very conveniently|securely) does support Workload Identity Federation. You should configure and use this to authenticate your app.
